# Question on sampling error

Tags: sampling, error

I have problem understanding following example in parentheses. Maybe you can help me.

Ideally, researchers know the full extent of the population they want to study, and they can select a sample from this population at random. Statisticians can calculate the probability that such random samples represent the population; this is
usually expressed in terms of sampling error (**for example, there
might be a 95 percent probability that the distribution of responses in a sample will be within 3 percent of the distribution in the population**).

Comment: This is explained in various contexts, such as the thread on sampling errors for polls at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16413/.  You may also find that searching our site for [sampling error](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22sampling+error%22) uncovers helpful explanations.

Answer (score 7):

The question in parentheses is incorrectly stated.  It is not the distribution of response that can be said to be within x% of the population distribution with some probability, it is the estimate from the random sample that can be claimed to cover with an interval x% wide the true parameter value with a specified probability. The statement in bold in the parentheses is not understandable because it does not make sense as stated.

Comment: Thanks michael. I have studied something about statistics at university, but i;m not a statistics professional. however, this phrase is stated in a book around social science

Comment: +1, throw away this book, it uses misleading language. Technically speaking, the design probabilities ARE the true probabilities, so one does not have to hide behind a shaky "repeated sampling" frequentist argument to justify the confidence intervals.